# How to install git and gatsby from docker

Tags: node.js, docker

I am trying to install git and gatsby from docker. Though i am able to install git, which seems to be running when i run "git status" after running docker exec -it  sh. But, gatsby does not work.

```
FROM node:alpine

# Also exposing VSCode debug ports
EXPOSE 8000 9929 9230

ARG SSG_HOME=/opt/ssg

WORKDIR $SSG_HOME

#Install Git

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache bash git openssh

#Install Gatsby

RUN apk add --update npm

RUN npm install gatsby-cli

COPY . $SSG_HOME

RUN npm run setup

ENTRYPOINT ["npm","run"]

CMD ["start-docker"]
```

I expect that it'll recognize the keyword gatsby, but it shows gatsby not found

```
$ docker exec -it db6e5a3518c0 sh
/opt/ssg # gatsby
sh: gatsby: not found
/opt/ssg #
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only installing it in a particular directory. Instead, go global:

```
RUN npm install -g gatsby-cli
```